What does にすると mean?

であるならば、何でもない素振りというのは彼にすると上出来の演技なのかもしれなかった。

"If that's the case, acting like nothing happened... may have been an excellent performance"
What does 彼にすると here mean? He's saying he didn't reveal the truth to his friend of what happened to his friend. Is にすると similar to なら?

～にする + conditional is a phrase to set a viewpoint or reference point. 彼にすると = 彼にしては = 彼としては = "for him; by his standards; in his standpoint".
Similar examples:

私としましては...
From my perspective... / As for me...
今日は冬にしては暖かい。
今日は冬としては暖かい。
Today is warm for a winter day.

